# Magento2 error message not showing in admin

Tags: magento2, plugin, before-plugin

I'm validating max sale qty when admin create order, I want to throw the error, it's redirecting back to order index page but error message not showing there? what's wrong here?

```
<?php
     
    namespace Vendor\Sales\Plugin;
     
    class Orderplugin {
    
     public function __construct(   
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,   
            \Magento\Quote\Model\MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteIdInterface $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId,
            \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockItemRepository,      
            \Magento\InventorySales\Model\GetProductSalableQty $salableQty,
            \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
             \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url, 
                \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
            ){
               
                $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;              
                $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId = $maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId;            
                $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
                $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;           
                $this->_salableQty = $salableQty;    
                $this->messageManager = $messageManager;   
                $this->url = $url;
                $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory; 
        }
        public function beforeSave(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject)
        {       
        
            $quoteId =  $subject->getQuoteId();      
                $quote_cart = $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteId);
                $quote_cart_items = $quote_cart->getAllItems(); 
                foreach($quote_cart_items as $item){ 
                    $stock_data = $this->_stockItemRepository->getStockItem($item->getProductId());          
                if($item->getQty()>$stock_data->getMaxSaleQty()){
                    $messge =  "Max allowed qty for product id with ".$item->getProductId().' is '.$stock_data->getMaxSaleQty();
                    $this->messageManager->addNotice($messge);
                    $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('sales/order');
                    $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
                    exit();     
                 }
                } 
        }
    }
```

Di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
    <plugin name="apr_sales_create" type="Vendor\Sales\Plugin\Orderplugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
</type>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share di.xml as well

Comment: I have added it, please check